Flag the max value in each column of a DataFrame as True and the rest as False
I have a DataFrame that I am rounding. After the round, I subtract the original from the resultant. This gives me a data frame with a shape identical to the original, but which contains the amount of change the rounding operation caused.
I need to transform this into a Boolean where there is a true flag for the max of the row, and everything else in the row is false. All steps but the final one are handled with a vectorized function. But I can't seem to figure out how to vectorize the last step. This is what I am currently doing:
a = pd.DataFrame([[2.290119, 5.300725, 17.266693, 75.134857, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.007606],
[0.000000, 7.560276, 55.579175, 36.858266, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.002284],
[0.001574, 15.225538, 39.309742, 45.373800, 0.000951, 0.001198, 0.087197],
[0.000000, 55.085390, 15.547927, 29.327661, 0.000000, 0.017691, 0.021331],
[0.000000, 66.283488, 15.636673, 17.912315, 0.000000, 0.003185, 0.164339]])

b = a.round(-1)  # round to 10's place (not 10ths)
c = b-a
round_modifier = c.apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.max()), axis="columns")
print(round_modifier)

       0      1      2      3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False  False  False  False

I am aware of DataFrame.idxmax(axis="columns"), which gives me the column name (of each row) where the max is found, but I can't seem to find a (pythonic) way to take that and populate the corresponding flag with a True.  The lambda expression I'm using gives the correct result, but I'm hoping for a faster method.
For anyone wondering, the use case is that I want to round the values in the original data frame to the tens place, such that they sum to 100.  I have pre-scaled this data so it should be close, but the rounding can cause the sum to come to 90 or 110.  I intend to use this T/F matrix to decide which rounded value caused the most delta, then round it in the opposite direction since this is the minimum impact method with which to coerce the series to properly sum to 100 in chunks of 10.

You can use idxmax to get the position of column with the max value, and use numpy broadcasting to match the position with the column.
m = c.columns.to_numpy() == c.idxmax(axis=1).to_numpy()[:, None]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, True, False), columns=c.columns)

End result:
    0     1     2     3     4     5     6
False False False  True False False False
False False  True False False False False
False  True False False False False False
False  True False False False False False
False False  True False False False False


This is a work of art!  Shortly after posting, I realized in extremely rare cases (1:150,000) I had multiple values in the row that were equal to the max.  The point of this is to "wiggle" one value to make the whole series sum to 100, but with multiple values getting flagged, we overshoot and miss the mark.  I immediately hoped that someone would post a solution that still used idmax() because it only flags the first one... thus avoiding this bug.  Thanks for coming through on this.  We went from about 45 seconds to mere milliseconds with this fix.  Thanks!  Marked as correct solution.

Glad I could help, but I made a small mistake in my code. You can remove np.where from the last line, it doesn't do anything.
pd.DataFrame(m, columns=c.columns)

Simply use max and eq:
c.eq(c.max(axis=1), axis=0)

Output:
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False  False  False  False


Using idxmax in combination with np.eye to create a Boolean mask where the maximum value in each row is flagged as True
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame([[2.290119, 5.300725, 17.266693, 75.134857, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.007606],
                  [0.000000, 7.560276, 55.579175, 36.858266, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.002284],
                  [0.001574, 15.225538, 39.309742, 45.373800, 0.000951, 0.001198, 0.087197],
                  [0.000000, 55.085390, 15.547927, 29.327661, 0.000000, 0.017691, 0.021331],
                  [0.000000, 66.283488, 15.636673, 17.912315, 0.000000, 0.003185, 0.164339]])

# Round the dataframe to the tens place
b = a.round(-1)

# Calculate the difference
c = b - a

# Get the index of the maximum value for each row
max_indices = c.idxmax(axis="columns")

# Create a Boolean mask where True corresponds to the maximum value in each row
round_modifier = np.zeros_like(c, dtype=bool)

# Use advanced indexing to set the True values
round_modifier[np.arange(len(c)), max_indices] = True

round_modifier_df = pd.DataFrame(round_modifier, columns=a.columns)
print(round_modifier_df)

output
    0      1      2      3      4      5      6
0  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False  False  False  False


If you are looking for a vectorized solution, one of the best ways to do that would be by using numpy. Once you have done the rounding, you can feed the whole array into it. This should lead to much faster calculations. If you are interested in reading more about the numpy max function here is the link. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.max.html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame([[2.290119, 5.300725, 17.266693, 75.134857, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.007606],
                  [0.000000, 7.560276, 55.579175, 36.858266, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.002284],
                  [0.001574, 15.225538, 39.309742, 45.373800, 0.000951, 0.001198, 0.087197],
                  [0.000000, 55.085390, 15.547927, 29.327661, 0.000000, 0.017691, 0.021331],
                  [0.000000, 66.283488, 15.636673, 17.912315, 0.000000, 0.003185, 0.164339]])

b = a.round(-1)  # round to 10's place (not 10ths)
c = b - a

# Use numpy for max and comparison
max_in_rows = np.max(c.values, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
round_modifier = c.values == max_in_rows
round_modifier_df = pd.DataFrame(round_modifier, columns=a.columns)
print(round_modifier_df)

